# how to get the performers of an event through facebook api?

Tags: facebook, api, events

i want the performers of an event using facebook api. There is no field like performers or artists in events in documentation. How do i get that?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no field available in the API for the data you're looking for, there's no way to fetch that data programmatically

I didn't actually realise there was a 'performers' field for Events on Facebook.com (none of the events i can see have such a field visible), perhaps examining the `description` field will contain the information you're looking for - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/event